# send message directly to whatsapp using context.startActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, code-reuse, start-activity

I want to send a message directly via whatsapp and I find the code below working. But it does not work and crash after I move the code into another java file as a common function call. So what is wrong? Thanks

before:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

after:

```
public void share2whatsapp(Context context) {

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: The context is not null. Yes, I find some information on the logcat and add the flag as follows:- sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);12-29 14:55:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 14:55:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13592): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? However, after I finish sending the first one and try to send another, whatsapp does not show the 2nd message. Is there still something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
public void share2whatsapp(Context context) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer. A code-only answer is generally not regarded as particularly useful.

Comment: sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  is added as suggested by the debugger